# JQuery detects keyup() and change() for same form AJAX request

Tags: ajax, jquery, keyup

I have a search form that I want to trigger an AJAX request, which contains both `<input type="text">` and `<select></select>` form elements.

I'd like to have the the AJAX request happen when someone starts typing, so I originally used:

```
$('#searchform').keyup(function() {
   //GRAB TEXT FROM INPUT AND START AJAX
});
```

but now the form has drop downs, so to tackle that I changed it to:

```
$('#searchform').change(function() {
   //GRAB VALUES FROM INPUT AND DROPDOWNS AND START AJAX
});
```

but that means it no longer starts the request whenever someone types anything in the `<input type="text">` field until I modify something else.

Is it possible to have a function run based on whether the form "changes" or whether the input field is typed in?  Should I write two functions or is there a selector that accomplishes this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you delegate the event, you could have your function run on both events, like so:

```
$('#searchform').on('keyup change', function() {
   //GRAB VALUES FROM INPUT AND DROPDOWNS AND START AJAX;
});
```

Just put a space between the events. [Here](http://jsbin.com/ogayex/1/edit) is a quick and dirty example.

Comment: Marked answered because it's quick n' dirty ;)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to listen to both events, but you can simplify this by connecting both to a single callback, namely, `update`.

```
var update = function() {
    // Handle update to form.
};

$('#searchform').keyup(update);
$('#searchform').change(update);
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a function to call the ajax and pass the value as parameter

```
function foo(x) {
   // ajax call with x
}

$('#searchform').keyup(function() {
   //GRAB TEXT FROM INPUT AND START AJAX
   foo($(this).val());
});

$('#searchform').change(function() {
   //GRAB VALUES FROM INPUT AND DROPDOWNS AND START AJAX
   foo($(this).val());
});
```